# Java time converter from input to minutes and hours

Tags: java

I have one Java question which wants me to convert seconds into hours and minutes.
For example, if the input is 3670 seconds, it works out to be 1 hour, 1 minute and 10 seconds. I have spent several hours and still cannot figure out. 
Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: instead of spending "several" hours for it, you could spend several seconds on google search (it depends on your internet connection speed as well).

Comment: lol,..................

Comment: public class question5
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        
       
        double second =Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double min = second /60;
        double hour = min /60;
        
        System.out.println("The converted minute time is "+ min);
        System.out.println("The converted hour time is "+ hour);
        
      }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int fullSeconds = ?;

int seconds = fullSeconds % 60;
int minutes = (fullSeconds/60) % 60;
int hours = fullSeconds/(60*60);
```

Comment: Hi, may I ask the meaning of this %? I cannot comprehend.

Comment: % is the modulo operator. Essentially it gives you the remainder after  dividing. So `61 % 60 == 1`,   `37 % 60 == 37`, `3621 % 60 == 21` etc

Comment: See the [Modulo Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is always in seconds you get:

```
minutes = input/60;
hours = minutes/60;
minutes -= hours*60;
seconds = input % 60;
```

Comment: That doesn't give the second count

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is trivial to do the modulo math by yourself. But as always with date/time questions in Java the standard answer (as for now, pre Java 8) for a library is [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), specifically the [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class.